# Parsing a file containing xml elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I have a big xml file which is composed of multiple xml files. The file structure is like this.

```
<xml1>
</xml1>
<xml2>
</xml2>
<xml3>
</xml3>
.
.
<xmln>
</xmln>
```

I want to process each XML file by a LINQ statement but I am not sure how to extract each XML element individually from the file and continue the iteration until the end. I figured experts here would be able to give me the nudge I am looking for. My requirement is to extract the individual elements so i could load into a XDoc element for further processing and continue on through the subsequent elements. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: have you tried `YourXmlDoc.GetElementByTagName("NameOfTag").InnerText`

Comment: Is it actually a complete XML file in itself, or is it *just* XML elements with no single root?

Comment: its just a text file with xml elements

Comment: It was created a error log which contains xml elements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each element is a valid XML, you can wrap your document in a top-level tag and then load it just fine:

```
<wrap>
  <xml1>
  </xml1>
  <xml2>
  </xml2>      
</wrap>
```

Comment: Anton Gogolev I was able to make it a XML document, how would i go about iterating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Xml reference, which includes a lot of built-in functionality, and it allows you to declare an XmlTextReader.  More info **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an error log with individual well formed xml elements, you probably don't want to load it as an `XMLDocument`. A better option is to use an `XPathDocument` created with an `XmlReader` where the `XmlReaderSettings` specify `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`. Then you can use an `XPathNavigator` to access your elements and attributes as needed. See the third answer in [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/c5687ce7-3386-4870-ab15-8e4aee5196e4/) for sample code.

...late by just a year and then some. :)